# How to increase Lookup column limit from 8

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, list-view-threshold, sharepoint-library

I am facing following problem:

```
'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
 Detail: The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup columns it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold enforced by the administrator.0x80070093
```

By following TechNet article: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary, I get to know that there can be maximum 8 columns. But by following the TechNet link, it says:

> To anyone having this same issue, we ended up having the SharePoint
>   Admin increase the limit on lookup columns from 8 to 60.  This
>   immediately resolved the issue.  The problem was that our domain admin
>   accounts would work because they are outside of the parameters of the
>   SharePoint rules set in our environment.

That means we can increase lookup columns !

I am a little confused; what's correct?

Comment: Yes, you can do it as correctly pholpar answered, but be aware of possible performance issues

Comment: For a good explanation for why you should not increase the threshold, refer to [this article](http://sympmarc.com/2012/07/23/sharepoints-list-view-lookup-threshold-and-why-we-dont-change-it). As an alternative, you can remove some of the lookup columns from your query results, or use workflow to copy their values to text columns and include those in the results instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Via Central Administration:
Manage web applications / Select the web application, then from the drop down list 'General Settings' select 'Resource Throttling' / change the value of 'List View Lookup Threshold'

Or via PowerShell:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://YourSharePointSite
$wa.MaxQueryLookupFields = 20
$wa.Update()
```