# Filter items based on lookup

Tags: 2013, list, rest, lookup-column, threshold

I have an SP list with 6000 items.It contains 10 lookup columns.
I want to filter,retrieve and display a set of items in a page based on these lookup value.

I tried using **REST API** & **CSOM** but I am getting an error saying that the threshold has been reached whenever I try to filter based on lookup column.The URL used in REST API is given below.

```
url:"sites/mysite/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Details')/Items?$select=Title,Sector/Title&$expand=Sector/Title&$filter= Sector/Title eq 'Banking'",
```

Also I want to filter based on Title of lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a setting on the farm. While it is configurable, you should probably leave it at its current settings.

You can find more resources about this in the links below.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2013/12/02/sharepoint-20102013-list-view-lookup-threshold-uncovered/

[How to Increasing Lookup column limit from 8](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132050/how-to-increasing-lookup-column-limit-from-8)

http://sympmarc.com/2012/07/23/sharepoints-list-view-lookup-threshold-and-why-we-dont-change-it/

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 8 Lookup columns in your list then you will Hit the Listview threshold, even if your return rows are less than 5K.

A couple of things.

- either reduce the number of lookup columns in the view and try again.
- Or Increase the ListView Threshold value for lookup column( this is not recommended as cause performance issue).